# Wildfly JSF resources: err_invalid_chunked_encoding

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsf, jboss, wildfly

My customer web application is currently on an AWS-EC2 Linux instance, running WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek".

I'm not using Apache or other web servers, just accessing the application server on port 8080 (the system is forwarding to 8080 all traffic on port 80).

Application works fine everywhere, but yesterday I found a very weird issue on one of my customer's browsers. However, it's not related to the browser, because I already tried installing Firefox and Chrome, in addition to IE, and the problem is still there. The client OS is Win8.1.

The CSS and JS files are not loaded by the browser: Chrome prints this message in the console:

> ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING

However, if I click on the file and 'Open link in new tab', I can actually see the file's content!

My static files are JSF resources, for example: 
**/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.htm?ln=primefaces&v=5.1**

Response headers are, for example:

```
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Fri, 27 Mar 2015 16:32:51 GMT
ETag:W/"312861-1427473269000"
Expires:Fri, 03 Apr 2015 16:32:51 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 27 Mar 2015 16:21:09 GMT
```

I saw the content-length is also zero, which I suppose is the cause for the problem.

How to find out more info on that? What's the solution for that type of error? Thanks

Comment: No! It's the first thing I tried:((

Comment: Do you have any request/response encoding filter enabled?

Comment: And maybe this? http://superuser.com/questions/893908/err-invalid-chunked-encoding-from-chrome

Comment: No filter at all. I tried that solution but nothing, they don't have any proxy server.